# C++ OpenGL glTexImage2D Access Violation

Tags: c++, opengl, access-violation, bmp, glteximage2d

I'm writing an application using OpenGL (freeglut and glew).

I also wanted textures so I did some research on the Bitmap file format and wrote a struct for the main header and another for the DIB header (info header).

Then I started writing the loader. It automatically binds the texture to OpenGL. Here is the function:

```
static unsigned int ReadInteger(FILE *fp)
{
    int a, b, c, d;

    // Integer is 4 bytes long.
    a = getc(fp);  
    b = getc(fp);  
    c = getc(fp);  
    d = getc(fp);

    // Convert the 4 bytes to an integer.
    return ((unsigned int) a) + (((unsigned int) b) << 8) +
           (((unsigned int) c) << 16) + (((unsigned int) d) << 24);
}

static unsigned int ReadShort(FILE *fp)
{
    int a, b;

    // Short is 2 bytes long.
    a = getc(fp);  
    b = getc(fp);

    // Convert the 2 bytes to a short (int16).
    return ((unsigned int) a) + (((unsigned int) b) << 8);
}

    GLuint LoadBMP(const char* filename)
{
    FILE* file;

    // Check if a file name was provided.
    if (!filename)
        return 0;

    // Try to open file.
    fopen_s(&file, filename, "rb");

    // Return if the file could not be open.
    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "Warning: Could not find texture '" << filename << "'." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Read signature.
    unsigned char signature[2];
    fread(&signature, 2, 1, file);

    // Use signature to identify a valid bitmap.
    if (signature[0] != BMPSignature[0] || signature[1] != BMPSignature[1])
    {
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }

    // Read width and height.
    unsigned long width, height;
    fseek(file, 16, SEEK_CUR); // After the signature we have 16bytes until the width.
    width = ReadInteger(file);
    height = ReadInteger(file);

    // Calculate data size (we'll only support 24bpp).
    unsigned long dataSize;
    dataSize = width * height * 3;

    // Make sure planes is 1.
    if (ReadShort(file) != 1)
    {
        cout << "Error: Could not load texture '" << filename << "' (planes is not 1)." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Make sure bpp is 24.
    if (ReadShort(file) != 24)
    {
        cout << "Error: Could not load texture '" << filename << "' (bits per pixel is not 24)." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Move pointer to beggining of data. (after the bpp we have 24 bytes until the data)
    fseek(file, 24, SEEK_CUR);

    // Allocate memory and read the image data.
    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[dataSize];

    if (!data)
    {
        fclose(file);
        cout << "Warning: Could not allocate memory to store data of '" << filename << "'." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    fread(data, dataSize, 1, file);

    if (data == NULL)
    {
        fclose(file);
        cout << "Warning: Could no load data from '" << filename << "'." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Close the file.
    fclose(file);

    // Create the texture.
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR); //NEAREST);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE); 

    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, width, height, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    return texture;
}
```

I know that the bitmap's data is correctly read because I outputted it's data to the console and compared with the image opened in paint.

The problem here is this line:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, dibheader.width,
    dibheader.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Most of the times I run the application this line crashes with the error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x008ffee9 in GunsGL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00af7002.

This is the Disassembly of where the error occurs:

```
movzx       ebx,byte ptr [esi+2]
```

It's not an error with my loader, because I've downloaded other loaders.
A downloaded loader that I used was [this one](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/collision_detection/17005/) from NeHe.

EDIT: (CODE UPDATED ABOVE)

I rewrote the loader, but I still get the crash on the same line. Instead of that crash, sometimes I get a crash on mlock.c (same error message is I recall correctly):

```
void __cdecl _lock (
        int locknum
        )
{

        /*
         * Create/open the lock, if necessary
         */
        if ( _locktable[locknum].lock == NULL ) {

            if ( !_mtinitlocknum(locknum) )
                _amsg_exit( _RT_LOCK );
        }

        /*
         * Enter the critical section.
         */

        EnterCriticalSection( _locktable[locknum].lock );
}
```

On the line:

```
EnterCriticalSection( _locktable[locknum].lock );
```

Also, here is a screen shot of one of those times the applications doesn't crash (the texture is obviously not right):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mtso.jpg

**Edit2:**

Updated code with the new working one.
(The reply marked as an answer does not contain all that was needed for this to work, but it was vital)

Comment: That memory location doesn't seem to be one indicating an uninitialized pointer... My next guess would be that OpenGL is trying to read beyond the bounds of `data`.  Can you verify that you're specifying the correct amount of data to read?

Comment: This looks more like C than C++

Comment: @ktodisco The data size is in fact correct.

Comment: @Pubby maybe, I don't really know the difference between them, I just code. xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know, it's tempting to read binary data like this

> ```
> BitmapHeader header;
> BitmapInfoHeader dibheader;
> /*...*/
> // Read header.
> fread(&header, sizeof(BitmapHeader), 1, file);
>
> // Read info header.
> fread(&dibheader, sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader), 1, file);
> ```

but you really shouldn't do it that way. Why? Because the memory layout of structures may be padded to meet alignment constraints (yes, I know about packing pragmas), the type size of the used compiler may not match the data size in the binary file, and last but not least endianess may not match.

Always read binary data into a intermediary buffer of which you extract the fields in a well defined way with exactly specified offsets and typing.

> ```
> // Allocate memory for the image data.
> data = (unsigned char*)malloc(dibheader.dataSize);
> ```

If this is C++, then use the `new` operator. If this is C, then don't cast from `void *` to the L value type, it's bad style and may cover usefull compiler warnings.

> ```
> // Verify memory allocation.
> if (!data)
> {
>     free(data);
> ```

If `data` is NULL you mustn't free it.

> ```
> // Swap R and B because bitmaps are BGR and OpenGL uses RGB.
> for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dibheader.dataSize; i += 3)
> {
>     B = data[i]; // Backup Blue.
>     data[i] = data[i + 2]; // Place red in right place.
>     data[i + 2] = B; // Place blue in right place.
> }
> ```

OpenGL does indeed support BGR alignment. The format parameter is, surprise, GL_BGR

> ```
> // Generate texture image.
> glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, dibheader.width, dibheader.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
> ```

Well, and this misses setting *all* of the pixel store parameters. Always set every pixel store parameter before doing pixel transfers, they may be left in some undesired state from a previous operation. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: I've tried GL_BGR a long time ago, I just get an undefined error.

Either way, I rewrote the loader, I'll update the question with the new code (and a different error comes from time to time).

Comment: @100GPing100: GL_BGR was introduced after OpenGL-1.1 so you need some extension header to use it. I recommend GLEW, although for just that token you don't need to initialize all function pointers.

Comment: I'm using glew actually (said in first post).

Do I need to "import" the types from it? (like in C# if we need a function from a dll we can import it)

Comment: @100GPing100: Well you need to include its header for it to be visible to the compiler. Also try GL_BGR_EXT. Note that it's only the 3rd last parameter that takes this, i.e. `glTexImage(…, GL_RGB, …, GL_BGR[_EXT], GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);`

Comment: @100GPing100: Well, did you set the pixel store parameters? All of them. See the manual page of glPixelStorei, the GL_UNPACK_ parameters are what you've got to take care of. http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPixelStore.xml and see this text on what those parameters mean  http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/chapter08.html

Comment: Be aware, I marked this question as the answer, but there's more things to know.

First off I was creating a pointer to a single unsigned byte. Second, I had to use gluBuild2DMipmaps instead of glTexture2D, else the texture would have no data for some reason.

Comment: @100GPing100: If you upload not all mipmap levels you must either disable mipmap filtering or limit the mipmap LOD range, otherwise, the texture will come out only white. This is a FAQ.

Comment: thanks, didn't know about that (didn't read the FAQ yet, just read some really basic tutorials and from there moved on alone).

Comment: @100GPing100: A problem may be your static assumption of 3 bytes per pixel. Use the BITMAP structures bmBitsPixel value to know the actual size for this.

Answer (score 13):

Try [`glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Texture_upload_and_pixel_reads) before your `glTexImage2D()` call.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried that already. The image is 24bpp 512x512. It crashes with the same error (just tried it again).